# how to implement a pin code activity for password recovery

Tags: android, user-interface

I am working on designing an activity the user use it to enter the pin code for recovering his password , but i could not know how to implement i need help , the required element look like the image :

[image]

Comment: what do you exactly want?plz elaborate..!

Comment: use one editText for each character. ( in this example you need 4 editText )

Comment: but the navigation between them how i con move the curser directly ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I took 4 custom edit text with property of getting selected when you press back. Here are the listeners and the CustomEditText elements

```
mCodeFourEt.setOnEditorActionListener(new EditText.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int actionId, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
                mConfirmBtn.performClick();
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }


    });


    mCodeTwoEt.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                String text = mCodeTwoEt.getText().toString();
                if (text.length() == 0) {
                    mCodeOneEt.requestFocus();
                    mCodeOneEt.selectAll();
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    mCodeThreeEt.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                String text = mCodeThreeEt.getText().toString();
                if (text.length() == 0) {
                    mCodeTwoEt.requestFocus();
                    mCodeTwoEt.selectAll();
                    return true;
                }
            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    mCodeFourEt.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
                String text = mCodeFourEt.getText().toString();
                if (text.length() == 0) {
                    mCodeThreeEt.requestFocus();
                    mCodeThreeEt.selectAll();
                    return true;
                }

            }

            return false;
        }
    });

    mCodeOneEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (mCodeOneEt.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                mCodeTwoEt.requestFocus();
            }

        }
    });

    mCodeTwoEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (mCodeTwoEt.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                mCodeThreeEt.requestFocus();
            }

        }
    });

    mCodeThreeEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
            if (mCodeThreeEt.getText().toString().length() > 0) {
                mCodeFourEt.requestFocus();
            }

        }
    });

    mCodeFourEt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Now here is the custom edittext class

```
public class CustomEditText extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText {


public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
}

public CustomEditText(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}

public CustomEditText(Context context) {
    super(context);
}


@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    return new ZanyInputConnection(super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs),
            true);
}

private class ZanyInputConnection extends InputConnectionWrapper {

    public ZanyInputConnection(InputConnection target, boolean mutable) {
        super(target, mutable);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean sendKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN
                && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL) {
            // Un-comment if you wish to cancel the backspace:
            // return false;
        }
        return super.sendKeyEvent(event);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean deleteSurroundingText(int beforeLength, int afterLength) {
        // magic: in latest Android, deleteSurroundingText(1, 0) will be called for backspace
        if (beforeLength == 1 && afterLength == 0) {
            // backspace
            return sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL))
                    && sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_UP, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
        }

        return super.deleteSurroundingText(beforeLength, afterLength);
    }

}
}
```

Just use this custom class in your XML and see the example above which is for 4 edit text.